# How can I use dropdown directive triggered by hover

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I need use the dropdown directive trigger by hover event?
Does it support that?
How can I use it?
Some thing like that

Button dropdown 
      
      
        Action
        Another action
        Something else here
        
        Separated link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropdown doesn't come builtin with this functionality, but you can utilized `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` to toggle it on mouse hover.

like this

```
<div class="btn-group" 

ng-mouseenter="status.isopen = true"
ng-mouseleave="status.isopen = false"

uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
<!-- rest of the markup-->
```

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4pdQL794NhhlISLB8Aq1?p=preview)

Comment: thx,but only using the ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave still has some problem,such as i must move quickly into dropdownMenu, otherwise it will close the menu immediately, i have rewrite the three directive to meet my need.

Comment: you can hack it a bit, you can place the directive inside a div, give that div some padding and attach the `ng-mouse..` to that div. now you won't have that gap, you can also play around with the position of the drop items but that seems much uglier

Comment: There still have gap between div and dropdownMenu.I rewrite the directive by setting mouseleave  a 500 ms timeout, when mouseover again,I cancel the timeout immediately,so the dropdown menu would not close now.